# Libgdx How to set render distance of PerspectiveCamera?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, libgdx

I already have a scene set up with the camera

```
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(80, w, h);
    cam.position.set(0, 0, -1);
    cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    cam.update();
```

But some of the scene is missing, because it is out of the camera's view distance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple, but not obvious:

to set the `perspectiveCamera`'s render distance, just add

```
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 500;
```

before `update()`.

Full source code:

```
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(80, w, h);
    cam.position.set(0, 0, -1);
    cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 500;
    cam.update();
```